Estoy realizando un proyecto en .net 8, la cuestion es que quiero implementar la previsualizacion de imagenes para un formulario, ¿Como puedo hacerlo?
Estoy implementando un formulario, una etiqueta input y otra para la imagen y el boton de carga, lo mas lejos que llegue es a incluir codigo en javascript pero que solo cumple con la previsualizacion luego de que aprete el boton una vez, y despues de ahi selecciono distintas imagenes
